# Dual booting Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 [same drive]

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 on the same drive.

I have already installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I have manually partitioned the drive.

300 MB boot; 20 GB root; 400 GB Home; 5GB Swap

500 GB is unpartitoned. (left for 14.04)

Now I want to install 14.04. How do i go about partitioning the remaining 500 GB for 14.04.

I will create another Home and root partition, but do I also have to create another boot partition? I don't want to have any grub issues. I just want both the installation to be separate and neat.

Comment: You do not need to create another boot partition. During install of 14.04 you have the option of installing alongside 12.04

Comment: I actually didn't want to do alongside installation and do it manually. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better way to do this. I have partitioned the drive as follows.

ext4 - 25GB; ext4 - 25GB; swap - 4GB; ext4 - remaining [to be used to store data]

So now I have 2 operating system in the 25gb partitions and use the data partition as a common data drive. I have written a complete tutorial if anyone is interested.

[How to dual boot 2 Ubuntu OS](http://www.techtint.com/how-to-dual-boot-two-linux-operating-systems/)